# Javascript: calling function inside another function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, runtime-error, object-expected

So inside my `<script>` tags, I have these functions.

```
$.fn.getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

function placeRandom() {
    alert(getRandom(1,7));
}
```

and I call the `placeRandom()` function like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    placeRandom();
});
```

when I do this, it gives me an

```
Object expected
```

error and refers to the line where I wrote

```
alert(getRandom(1.7));
```

Now, my main question is if there is anything wrong with the code which I am showing you, or does it look correct? Because if it looks correct then I think i'm going to have to run through the rest of my entire code and look for maybe a open bracket which isn't closed because that might be the problem. So yea, is there any problem with my placeRandom() or getRandom() function or is the error occuring because of another reason other than these functions?

Comment: You are binding `getRandom` to the jQuery namespace, you will only be able to access it through a jQuery object instance or via `$.fn.getRandom()`

Comment: with the way you are calling `getRandom`, i think you just want a standard function. `getRandom function(min,max)...`

Comment: Why are you using `$.fn`?

Comment: Oh, okay, I will change it to getRandom function() instead.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. Only attach a function to jQuery if you want to integrate it in the library (like a plug-in). See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is were you are defining the `getRandom` function. You are putting it in the jQuery.fn namespace. If you organize your code like the following it should work much better.

```
var getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

var placeRandom = function() {
    alert(getRandom(1,7));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    placeRandom();
});
```

**Additional Info:**
jQuery.fn is actually a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) but is commonly referred to as a namespace in this specific context.

Comment: That's a prototype, not a namespace.

Comment: Very true, I will clarify in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `getRandom` to the jQuery namespace, you will only be able to access it through a jQuery object instance or via `$.fn.getRandom()`

So unless you want to be able to call it like `$(selector).getRandom()`, just declare it as a standard function.

Comment: That's a prototype, not a namespace.

Comment: It's a namespace pointing to the jQuery prototype. Wanna argue semantics?

Comment: Yes, it will. Try it :)

Comment: In JavaScript, functions are [first class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), which means you can do a lot of fun stuff with them, such as passing them as arguments to other functions, storing their references in variables or using them in objects.

Answer (score 1):

you are binding `getRandom` to the $ namespace (jQuery). so you have to call it `$.fn.getRandom(1,7)` or define the function the following:

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```